# Web scrapping & convert it to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm having problem to scrap the fetched website  [https://ditppu.menlhk.go.id/apippu/gis/sebaranEnergi/tahun/2022/param//kategori//subkategori/](https://stackoverflow.com)

I used this code to scrap & convert it to DataFrame, but the result are not in the correct format

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://ditppu.menlhk.go.id/apippu/gis/sebaranEnergi/tahun/2022/param//kategori//subkategori/")

data = response.json()

data1 = data['rows']

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what do you mean by wrong format, what are you expecting ?

Comment: Hi Abhay. The DataFrame did not display the data values in separate columns. I'm trying to get the values of [nilai] to be in separate column. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what output you want but if you want to extract the "nilai" key value in the json you can use below

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.json
from pandas import json_normalize

response = requests.get("https://ditppu.menlhk.go.id/apippu/gis/sebaranEnergi/tahun/2022/param//kategori//subkategori/")
data = response.json()

rows = data['rows']
data_list = []

for key in rows:
    nilai = rows[key]['nilai']
    for nil in nilai:
        data_row = {
            'nilai': nil['nilai'],
            'nama': nil['nama'],
            'nilai_val': nil['nilai_val'],
            'satuan': nil['satuan'].replace("<sup>", "^").replace("</sup>", "")
        }
        data_list.append(data_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=['nilai', 'nama', 'nilai_val', 'satuan'])
df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Outputs a csv like below
[image]

Comment: Hi Abhay, thanx for the suggestions